# Dash home as was in 11.04

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move the  Dash launcher home button to the panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122303/how-to-move-the-dash-launcher-home-button-to-the-panel)

Is there any way to have the «Dash home» icon as was in Natty, I mean, not as part of the dash but of the panel?