# How to move the  Dash launcher home button to the panel?

Tags: unity, launcher

Is it possible to use the Natty BFB (Ubuntu button that opens the dash) in Precise?

I really liked the design of having the button on the menu as opposed to having it on the launcher.

Comment: Right now it is not possible to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also liked the Dash launcher on the panel, it made the two bars seem more integrated and didn't make me dislike Unity as much.  I don't like the current look either.  As Manish Sinha pointed out in his comment above, there is currently no way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked how to patch it, which goes further.  It would be a good bit of work, likely.  I think there would be two separate jobs, removing it from the Launcher, and adding it to the panel.

- I tried to find a Q&A about removing the 'BFB' that opens the dash, from the Launcher, but I couldn't.  I have some suspicion it's out there, though.
- To put it in the panel, you could write an indicator that would go into the Panel--each of the elements in the panel is an indicator program, usually their own package, like indicator-session, indicator-appmenu, etc.  Challenges there would include getting it to appear on the left, while avoiding collisions with the window-close buttons.

I don't know if you'd really want to do all this, and I'm not an expert on building these things, but I hope this could de-mystify the subject, a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a way in Ubuntu, but it isn't a configuration option, so you'd have to patch it in yourself if you wanted that.

Comment: which is another way of saying **NO**

Comment: How do I patch it?